# Como importar coluna especifica de arquivo txt

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Gostaria de saber se é possível importar uma coluna especifica de um arquivo txt pra minha planilha do excel? E como poderia ser feito

Tenho uma macro que importa o arquivo txt já pronto, porém preciso de um botão onde eu clico, seleciono meu arquivo e ele já importa os dados daquela coluna com os dados específicos que eu quero

OBS: Preciso que importe apenas a coluna de "Status"

[image: Importar Apenas Dados da coluna "Status"]

Código feito para importação de txt:

```
Sub EncontrarTXT()


Dim arquivo As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet


Set Objeto = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject") 'Criando objeto

arquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt") 'Para abrir o documento, janelinha do explorer

If arquivo = "" Or arquivo = "Falso" Then 'Se arquivo for igual a vazio, ou se ele clicar em cancelar retornar "falso", usuï¿½rio nï¿½o selecionou nenhum documento
Exit Sub
End If



Open arquivo For Input As #1

Worksheets("Status").Activate 'Referencia o objeto para que seja ativada a opção de abrir uma nova planilha

lin = 1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, valorLin
    Cells(lin, 4).Value = valorLin
    lin = lin + 1
Loop

Close #1

Range("D4:D" & lin - 1).TextToColumns Other:=True 'Intervalo em que é inserido os dados e separando por colunas para o tipo de dado escolhido
Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Faz o ajuste de colunas para obter a melhor largura

End Sub
```

---

```html
Total:86

CCD (20)
ARE-SIS         ID          Status          Resumo
999 - 10    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX HOMOLOGADA  Consulta saldo devedor no portal consignado
999 - 11    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Compensação do IOF no redirecionamento
999 - 12    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Consignação Siape - Alteração de Contratos
999 - 13    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX EM HOMOLOGAÇÃO  Alterar opção de baixa manual de parcelas para que sempre seja condicionada a saldo.
999 - 14    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de conta corrente - CCD
999 - 15    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX CANCELADA   Contabilização Individualizada na conciliação BRBSERV
999 - 16    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Cartão consignado
999 - 17    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX CANCELADA   Melhoria de performance CCDJM400 / CCDP62
999 - 18    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Melhoria de Performance CCDJ1700 - CCDPZE - CCDPQR
999 - 19    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Melhoria CCDJD300 / CCDP20
999 - 20    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Melhoria de Performance CCDJM100 - CCDP40
999 - 09    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Alteração do simulador de campanha
999 - 08    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Consignado Privado
999 - 07    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Liquidação e baixa de parcelas
999 - 06    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Cobrança de IOF complementar das parcelas atrasadas do CCD
999 - 05    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX EM TESTE    Alterar o envio da informação da CONTA EXTERNA pelo CCD para os arquivos CTRAA2 e CTRAA5
999 - 04    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    2ª fase do e-Consignado API: Averbação on-line
999 - 03    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Criação de relatório e consignado
999 - 02    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    E-consignado 2a parte
999 - 01    CCD-XXXXXXXXXXX EM IMPLANTAÇÃO  Ajuste CCD para 144 parcelas - Automação
CTC (8)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 08    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM TESTE    Melhoria de Performance CTCP07
999 - 07    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX HOMOLOGADA  Melhoria Performance CTCN48
999 - 06    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Envio da quantidade de parcelas em aberto CTC
999 - 05    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Reter portabilidade pelo motivo mais adequado
999 - 03    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Sistema CTC apresentar XML's recebidas
899 - 04    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Preparar o sistema CTC para portar contratos do TSP
005 - 02    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO  Atualização arquivos CTC (Troca de modalidade e Cheque Especial)
005 - 01    CTC-XXXXXXXXXXX HOMOLOGADA  Inclusão de novos arquivos (Troca de Modalidade e Cheque Especial)
DSC (3)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 03    DSC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Atualizar Conta Externa COSIF enviada do DSC para o CTR
999 - 02    DSC-XXXXXXXXXXX REJEITADA   Baixa com consulta saldo Sim
999 - 01    DSC-XXXXXXXXXXX AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO  Resolução 4.790 do Bacen-Autorização e cancelamento de autorização de débitos em conta
EAC (10)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 10    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de Conta Corrente - EAC
999 - 09    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Criar opções de Estorno e de Cancelamento da Baixa e da Liberação
999 - 08    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM CANCELAMENTO Projeto DT-e Criação de Antecipação EAC
999 - 07    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Marcação dos Índices Flutuantes - Integração EAC-CTR
999 - 06    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Baixa com consulta saldo Sim
999 - 05    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Atualizar Conta Externa COSIF enviada do EAC para o CTR
999 - 04    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    ADEQUAR SISTEMA LEGADO A NOVA TABELA DE TAFIFAS.
999 - 03    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX REJEITADA   Baixa não integrada com o DCC
010 - 02    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX HOMOLOGADA  [Carta Circular 3.896] Carga inicial do enquadramento contábil
010 - 01    EAC-XXXXXXXXXXX AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO  [Carta Circular 3.896] Marcação no contrato de "possui garantia de imóvel do próprio devedor"
ECC (14)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 10    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Ajuste de operações encerradas no ECC
999 - 11    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Gerar arquivos e relatórios - Normativo SARB 019/2018
999 - 12    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Ajuste contabilidade PF e PJ - atividade
999 - 13    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Correção de erros de integração com CTR (CTRRR8)
999 - 14    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX HOMOLOGADA  Melhoria de Performance ECCPZ8
999 - 15    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Melhoria de Performance ECCJD300
999 - 16    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de conta corrente - ECC
999 - 17    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Melhoria de Performance ECCJS400/ECCPC7
999 - 09    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Alteração das sub-rotinas ECC (pré-aprovado) para inclusão de indicador de Seguro SIM ou NÃO
999 - 08    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Renovacao Automatica Produto CBE 030 ECC
999 - 07    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Atualizar Conta Externa COSIF enviada do ECC para o CTR
999 - 06    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM TESTE    Alteração da Funcionalidade Vencimento Antecipado
999 - 05    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO  Alteração na Forma de Contratação de Limites de Cheque Especial
005 - 04    ECC-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO [Res. 4.762] Portabilidade Crédito Rotativo
FCG (4)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 07    FCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de conta corrente - FCG
999 - 03    FCG-XXXXXXXXXXX REJEITADA   Baixa com consulta saldo Sim
999 - 02    FCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Atualizar Conta Externa COSIF enviada do FCG para o CTR
999 - 01    FCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Manutenção da Antecipação de Recebíveis CIP
OCA (8)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 08    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Apropriação de rendas
999 - 07    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de conta corrente - OCA
999 - 06    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Ajuste Sub-rotina Simulador de Renegociação SBE
999 - 05    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Alterações de acessos no OCA pelo perfl GECAT
999 - 04    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Baixa por arquivo - VENDA DE CARTEIRA
999 - 03    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX EM TESTE    Integração OCA e MGF - prejuízo
999 - 02    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Criar relatório de conciliação PCLD para o sistema OCA
999 - 01    OCA-XXXXXXXXXXX REJEITADA   Evolução da renegociação OCA
OCG (19)
ARE-SIS ID  Status  Resumo
999 - 10    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Correção de erros de integração com CTR (CTRRR8)
999 - 11    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Compensação do IOF no redirecionamento
999 - 12    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Reconhecimento da liquidação dos contratos com situação Portabilidade
999 - 13    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Marcação de índices flutuantes - Integração OCG-CTR
999 - 14    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Cartão Construção
999 - 15    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Novo Simulador de Operações Parceladas
999 - 16    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Repactuação OCG
999 - 17    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM CANCELAMENTO Projeto DT-e Criação de Antecipação OCG
999 - 18    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Parcelamento de fatura via canal
999 - 19    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Transferência de conta corrente - OCG
999 - 09    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Alteração de valor informado Portabilidade OCG
999 - 08    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SUSPENSA    Liquidação e baixa de parcelas
999 - 07    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX SOLICITADA  Remodelar o produto 324 – BRB Credreforma, com alteração do nome para BRB Energia renovável
999 - 06    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Compra Carteira FGTS Banco PAN - Etapa II
999 - 05    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Criação de Limite de Pré-aprovado para liberação nos Canais
999 - 04    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Consulta/Bloqueio do Saldo Saque Aniversário FGTS via API
999 - 03    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO API para comunicação entre o BRB e a Caixa Econômica Federal (FGTS)
999 - 02    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Troca de arquivos para operacionalização do produto Antecipação FGTS
999 - 01    OCG-XXXXXXXXXXX EM EXECUÇÃO Automatização Carga Compra Carteira
```

Comment: Qual é o problema com o seu código?

Comment: Não há problemas, no caso o código acima funciona apenas para importar o arquivo txt. Gostaria que ele importasse somente a coluna "Status" e não o txt inteiro, e estou com dificuldade sobre isso.

Comment: O espaçamento entre as colunas é feito com o quê? 1 tabulação, múltiplos espaços ou uma mistura dos dois?

Comment: Creio que a mistura dos dois, por isso uso o "Other:=True"

Comment: Manda um conjunto de dados de exemplo, pra gente poder testar, pode ser?

Comment: Certo, o conjunto de dados que quero importar (.txt) é esse a seguir, como não consigo upar o txt aqui irei mandar os dados e vc transforma em um txt ai ok? Lembrando, quero que importe somente o contéudo da coluna de STATUS, como: HOMOLOGADA, SOLICITADA, EM EXECUÇÃO, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Salve!

Você é o mesmo cara que tinha feito a pergunta sobre abrir múltiplos arquivos .TXT, né? A resposta serviu pra você?

Sua situação só é difícil porque o arquivo de texto que você precisa iterar não tem nenhum delimitador previsível para a coluna. Ele sempre começa depois de um "-XXXXXXXXX ", o que é bom, mas não temos como saber onde ele termina. Às vezes, ele termina em um espaço só, embora na maioria seja em dois espaços e eventualmente possa ser uma tabulação. Por este motivo, eu acho que uma Expressão Regular, buscando uma lista dos status possíveis, é a melhor solução.

Testei aqui e deu certo.

Observações:

1. Se houver status que não estiverem na lista da expressão regular, é só inserir o status novo (*case sensitive*) no `Pattern`, na função `PegarColuna`, separado do anterior por uma barra vertical (`|`).
2. Na janela do desenvolvedor do VBA, você precisa ir ao menu Ferramentas -> Referências e, na janela Referências, marcar a biblioteca `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0` (estão em ordem alfabética).
3. O arquivo TXT costuma estar codificado em UTF-8, e nesse caso a importação utilizando o `Open` vai deformar os caracteres com acentos. Se isso acontecer para você, para funcionar, basta abrir o arquivo TXT antes, "Salvar Como" e escolher alguma codificação UTF-16 (eu usei a `UTF-16 LE` e funcionou). Aí os acentos serão reconhecidos (outra pessoa que passou por isso [aqui](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/VBA/language/statements/open/character-encoding)).

Segue o código:

```
Sub EncontrarTXT()
    Dim arquivo As String, valorLin As String
    Dim lin As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    arquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt") 'Para abrir o documento, janelinha do explorer
    If arquivo = "" Or arquivo = "Falso" Then Exit Sub
    Set sht = Worksheets("Status")
    
    Open arquivo For Input As #1
    
    lin = 1
    
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, valorLin
        sht.Cells(lin, 4).Value = PegarColuna(valorLin)
        lin = lin + 1
    Loop
    
    Close #1
    
    sht.Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Faz o ajuste de colunas para obter a melhor largura
End Sub

Function PegarColuna(LinhaCompleta As String) As String
    Dim regexObj As New RegExp, matches As VBScript_RegExp_10.MatchCollection
    Dim resp As String
    
    With regexObj
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(-X+ )(HOMOLOGADA|SOLICITADA|EM EXECUÇÃO|EM HOMOLOGAÇÃO|CANCELADA|SUSPENSA|EM TESTE|EM IMPLANTAÇÃO|AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO|REJEITADA|EM CANCELAMENTO){1}( ?)"
        Set matches = .Execute(LinhaCompleta)
    End With
        
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        resp = matches(0)
        resp = Split(resp, " ", 2)(1)
        resp = Trim(resp)
    Else
        resp = "" 'Se não achar o Pattern acima, ele retorna uma string vazia
    End If
    
    PegarColuna = resp
End Function
```

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora não tive tempo desde então! Sim, sou eu mesmo kkkk. Mas enfim, não funcionou, adicionei o código porém ele só está puxando a palavra "SUSPENSA" e não as demais da coluna. O restante fica tudo em branco, e uma palavra SUSPENSA na célula 21

Comment: O txt está salvo como utf-8?

Comment: UTF-8 é o padrão, mas tem que salvar como UTF 16 pra funcionar.

Comment: Não aparece essa opção, apenas: ANSI, UNICODE, unicode big endian e UTF-8. Essa UTF-16 tenho que fazer uma configuração no pc para habilitar, certo? Irei atrás de habilitar e confirmo aqui se deu certo com a macro

Comment: UTF é Unicode. Tente essa Big Endian, que é um tipo de UTF-16.

Comment: continua o mesmo, só importa a palavra "SUSPENSA" na 4 coluna, célula 21. O restante fica tudo em branco, mas vi que você havia dito que o motivo de usar o UTF 16 seria por acentuação, mas as outras palavras não tem acento também, porém so importa essa SUSPENSA

Comment: Mesmo com esse Big Endian e os demais que citei é o mesmo resultado, importação de apenas essa única palavra

Comment: Ok. Você pode colocar o seu TXT num repositório (por exemplo o GitHub, ou outro drive) e colocar o link aqui? Pode ser que a operação de copiar e colar nessa tela tenha mudado um caractere invisível para um espaço simples.

Comment: Certo, coloquei no github e no "README" especifiquei o que estou fazendo, e coloquei o projeto pra vc dar uma olhada se quiser

Comment: https://github.com/AlaxAtaide/VBAtest

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa interessante é utilizar os recursos do Power Query. Com ele podemos trabalhar com diversos recursos de separação, quebra, adição, concatenamento, e etc. de forma a conseguir, por exemplo, importar apenas essa coluna (embora não veja sentido inicialmente em importar apenas essa coluna). Segue o código para ser colocado no Editor Avançado do Power Query, tendo em vista o seguinte:

1. O texto que você anexou foi salvo como Texto.TXT
2. Adapte o caminho da fonte, que no código a seguir é: "C:\Users\ALeXceL\Desktop\Excel\LAB\Texto.TXT"

Após colar o código no Editor Avançado, lembro que pode-se acessar cada passo que fiz, no diálogo "Etapas Aplicadas" do Power Query.

```
let
    Fonte = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ALeXceL\Desktop\Excel\LAB\Texto.TXT"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Fonte,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Linhas Principais Removidas" = Table.Skip(#"Tipo Alterado",1),
    #"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Linhas Principais Removidas", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("  ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7", "Column1.8", "Column1.9", "Column1.10", "Column1.11", "Column1.12", "Column1.13", "Column1.14", "Column1.15"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", type text}, {"Column1.8", type text}, {"Column1.9", type text}, {"Column1.10", type text}, {"Column1.11", type text}, {"Column1.12", type text}, {"Column1.13", type text}, {"Column1.14", type text}, {"Column1.15", type text}}),
    #"Outras Colunas Removidas" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Tipo Alterado1",{"Column1.3"}),
    #"Dividir Coluna pela Posição" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Outras Colunas Removidas", "Column1.3", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 16}, false), {"Column1.3.1", "Column1.3.2"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Dividir Coluna pela Posição",{{"Column1.3.1", type text}, {"Column1.3.2", type text}}),
    #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{"Column1.3.1"}),
    #"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Colunas Removidas", "Column1.3.2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.3.2.1", "Column1.3.2.2", "Column1.3.2.3", "Column1.3.2.4", "Column1.3.2.5", "Column1.3.2.6", "Column1.3.2.7", "Column1.3.2.8", "Column1.3.2.9", "Column1.3.2.10", "Column1.3.2.11", "Column1.3.2.12", "Column1.3.2.13", "Column1.3.2.14"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Dividir Coluna por Delimitador1",{{"Column1.3.2.1", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.2", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.3", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.4", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.5", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.6", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.7", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.8", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.9", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.10", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.11", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.12", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.13", type text}, {"Column1.3.2.14", type text}}),
    #"Colunas Removidas1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo Alterado3",{"Column1.3.2.3", "Column1.3.2.4", "Column1.3.2.5", "Column1.3.2.6", "Column1.3.2.7", "Column1.3.2.8", "Column1.3.2.9", "Column1.3.2.10", "Column1.3.2.11", "Column1.3.2.12", "Column1.3.2.13", "Column1.3.2.14"}),
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Colunas Removidas1",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1.3.2.2"}),
    #"Valor Substituído1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Valor Substituído",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1.3.2.1"}),
    #"Personalização Adicionada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Valor Substituído1", "Personalizar", each [Column1.3.2.1]&" "&[Column1.3.2.2]),
    #"Colunas Removidas2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personalização Adicionada",{"Column1.3.2.1", "Column1.3.2.2"}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Colunas Removidas2", each ([Personalizar] <> "")),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Linhas Filtradas",{{"Personalizar", "Status"}}),
    #"Linhas Filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Colunas Renomeadas", each ([Status] <> " "))
in
    #"Linhas Filtradas1"
```

Para o caso de preferir uma solução de importação no VBA, segue rotina que utiliza o objeto ADODB (Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library). No caso de necessidade de cadastramento de nova string "Status", adicione-a no código. Isto pode ser melhorado a partir de um controle numa guia de planilha, para que o código sempre leia a tabela atualizada. Você também deve melhorar essa questão da importação, adicionando código que controle/verifique se o arquivo já havia sido importado antes, evitando duplicidade de informação.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnImportarTXTStatus()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim oWs As Worksheet
    Dim objADOStream As Object
    Dim strLine As String
    Dim arrStatus() As Variant
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    Const adReadLine = -2

    arrStatus = Array("HOMOLOGADA", "SOLICITADA", "EM EXECUÇÃO", "EM HOMOLOGAÇÃO", _
                      "CANCELADA", "SUSPENSA", "EM TESTE", "EM IMPLANTAÇÃO", _
                      "AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO", "REJEITADA", "EM CANCELAMENTO")

    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objADOStream.Type = 2
    objADOStream.Open

    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt")
    If strFile = "" Or strFile = "Falso" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    objADOStream.LoadFromFile strFile
    objADOStream.LineSeparator = 10
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do Until objADOStream.EOS
        strLine = objADOStream.ReadText(adReadLine)
        For intStatus = LBound(arrStatus) To UBound(arrStatus)
            If InStr(strLine, arrStatus(intStatus)) > 0 Then
                'Stop
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").Activate
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").Range("D1:D5000").End(xlUp).Activate
                Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
                Loop
                ActiveCell.Value = arrStatus(intStatus)
            End If

        Next
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    objADOStream.Close

    Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit    'Faz o ajuste de colunas para obter a melhor largura
lblExit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: É que para esse caso Alex, preciso de um botão onde o usuário clica "Importar dados atualizados" e importa essa coluna especifica com somente os status que foram atualizado. Entende? assim vendo o progresso do status de tal agencia, tal data estava em solicitada, depois foi pra em execução, etc... Então creio que com o PowerQuery não dê certo (eu acho)

Comment: O Power Query é um aplicativo completo dentro do próprio Excel (e do Power BI). Tem uma interface gráfica bem amigável e utiliza a linguagem M, que tem mais de 700 comandos à disposição do programador. Mas entendo sua necessidade e, mais logo, posto outra solução, bem simples até.

Comment: Poderia listar todos os Status possíveis de serem exibidos?

Comment: Pela macro, está puxando os dados inseridos na macro na parte "Status", porém não está puxando exatamente o que está no TXT por exemplo a ordem deles, exemplo: https://imgur.com/YWqXcfA e o "strLine = objADOStream.ReadText(adReadLine)" está dando o seguinte erro: Erro em tempo de execução, parametro incorreto

Comment: Status possiveis de serem exibidos: ("HOMOLOGADA", "SOLICITADA", "EM EXECUÇÃO", "EM HOMOLOGAÇÃO", _
                      "CANCELADA", "SUSPENSA", "EM TESTE", "EM IMPLANTAÇÃO", _
                      "AGUARDANDO HOMOLOGAÇÃO", "REJEITADA", "EM CANCELAMENTO", "SUSPENSA PELO TESTE")

Comment: Tenho um seguinte problema, ta vendo pela print que enviei que tenho uma coluna com os seguintes id? em tais ordens, porém quando importo novo txt ele muda as ordens dessas ids podem estar diferentes, então quando eu importasse uma nova coluna com esses dados estaria diferente, pois estaria apresentando o status de outra id, pois trocou a ordem. A pergunta é, como não tem um padrão nessas id, como não seguem uma ordem certa sempre, não é possivel fazer macro para isso certo?

Comment: Coloquei o arquivo.txt aberto junto da planilha, conferi, estão exatamente na ordem como está no (meu) arquivo texto.txt. Faça isso também, lembrando de limpar toda a informação previamente colocada pela macro. Deixe apenas o título "Status". Não experimentei problema aqui com a linha que você mencionou estar apresentando erro. Se for o caso, envie o TXT com o qual está trabalhando agora.

Comment: Você postou dizendo que queria importar apenas a coluna STATUS (eu comentei que não via muito sentido nisso). Você, em verdade, está precisando de uma macro que leia o TXT e adicione a um banco de dados as informações tratadas. Vi também que o layout de seu print inicial é diferente daquele que consta no seu print mais recente, notadamente em relação aos 'CDD'. Para tanto importe pelo menos as duas colunas para, em seguida, atualizar adequadamente seu banco.

Comment: É não seria possivel ter um banco de dados para isso, então esquece o que disse vou ver outra forma para isso mas quanto ao que me disse para deixar o txt aberto a planilha, mesmo assim não funcionou continua importando daquele jeito que havia dito

Comment: Uma dúvida importante, há uma forma de importar os dados do txt apenas de CCD? Exemplo: https://imgur.com/TMmdBNZ ele importa apenas os dados que se encontra ao CCD e quanto encontrar a palavra seguinte "CTC" ele para, assim inserindo dados apenas dessa categoria